# Edit Page Issue

Tags: web-part, edit

I created a custom list then I created a web-part page usage the custom list. I want to edit the webpart. But when I click the "Edit Page" I'm getting the following error. What is the reason for this issue?

[image]

ULS Logs

> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.11     w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0   a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>   01/05/2015 15:34:27.11  w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>
> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.11     w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           SPRequest                       8e3n    Medium      token timestamp is in the future. probably machine clock out of sync    a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>
> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.12     w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>
> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.12     w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,4 agb9s,10 aat87   a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>
> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.12     w3wp.exe (0x2264)                           0x12B4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request ("site link " ErrorText=Exception%20of%20type%20%27System%2EArgumentException%27%20was%20thrown%2E%0D%0AParameter%20name%3A%20encodedValue)). Execution Time=20.4704   a9c7dc9c-36f2-c067-e92a-09660d1c7897
>
> 01/05/2015 15:34:27.67     DistributedCacheService.exe (0x2A4C)        0x1694  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ahlcq   Medium      Calling... SPDistributedCacheClusterCustomProvider:: BeginTransaction

[image]

Comment: Try to refresh the page. If the issue still appear then click on Technical Details, and copy the correlation id, search in the ULS logs.

Comment: @AmalHashim I refreshed the page again and I can edited. But when I finished edit process I clicked Ok and I got error. I looked ULS Logs. I added logs and screnshhot of image under my question. Please check my questions again.

Comment: Zengel: Check the date time on all the servers. It seems the time is out of sync.

Comment: AmalHashim: How can I check date time? What should I look?

Comment: Zengel: Its the system clock you can see it in the task bar.